# How to control QGroupBox resizing

Tags: python, pyqt, qgroupbox

The code below creates a single dialog with `GroupBox()` resizing in sync with the dialog. This is default resizing policy for GroupBox. How to change this policy so `GroupBox` occupies as little space (area) as possible and never expands vertically. How to achieve it?

[image]

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
app = QtGui.QApplication([])

panel=QtGui.QDialog()
panel.setLayout(QtGui.QVBoxLayout())

groupbox = QtGui.QGroupBox('Group Box')
groupbox.setLayout(QtGui.QVBoxLayout())
panel.layout().addWidget(groupbox)

for i in range(3):
    row = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
    row.addWidget(QtGui.QLabel('Label'))
    row.addWidget(QtGui.QLineEdit())
    row.addWidget(QtGui.QPushButton('Push Button'))
    groupbox.layout().addLayout(row)

panel.layout().addWidget(QtGui.QPushButton('Confirm'))

panel.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: Try something like `panel.layout().addWidget(QtGui.QSpacerItem(20, 40, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QSizePolicy.Expanding)` right before the confirm button to add a vertical spacer.

Comment: Put `panel.layout().addStretch()` after the group-box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest one by ekhumoro:

[image]

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
app = QtGui.QApplication([])

panel=QtGui.QDialog()
panel.setLayout(QtGui.QVBoxLayout())

groupbox = QtGui.QGroupBox('Group Box')
groupbox.setLayout(QtGui.QVBoxLayout())
panel.layout().addWidget(groupbox)
panel.layout().addStretch()

for i in range(3):
    row = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
    row.addWidget(QtGui.QLabel('Label'))
    row.addWidget(QtGui.QLineEdit())
    row.addWidget(QtGui.QPushButton('Push Button'))
    groupbox.layout().addLayout(row)

panel.layout().addWidget(QtGui.QPushButton('Confirm'))

panel.show()
app.exec_()
```

The second approach works as well after we replace `.addWidget` with `.addItem`:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
app = QtGui.QApplication([])

panel=QtGui.QDialog()
panel.setLayout(QtGui.QVBoxLayout())

groupbox = QtGui.QGroupBox('Group Box')
groupbox.setLayout(QtGui.QVBoxLayout())
panel.layout().addWidget(groupbox)
panel.layout().addItem(QtGui.QSpacerItem(20, 40, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding))
for i in range(3):
    row = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
    row.addWidget(QtGui.QLabel('Label'))
    row.addWidget(QtGui.QLineEdit())
    row.addWidget(QtGui.QPushButton('Push Button'))
    groupbox.layout().addLayout(row)

panel.layout().addWidget(QtGui.QPushButton('Confirm'))

panel.show()
app.exec_()
```